# Ensure rows are fully complete before new rows of data can be entered

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to restrict users in excel of adding data to new rows in a table unless all data has been entered in the previous row, can someone help?  I currently have conditional formatting that highlights any row that has missing data, but I wanted to take it beyond this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no easy way to *prevent* data entry on a new row.

However, you could use the `Worksheet_Change` event to *test* for complete entry, and undo the new data entry if the previous rows is incomplete.

Something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim lr As ListRow

    ' Get reference to the first or only Table in the worksheet
    Set lo = Me.ListObjects(1)

    ' If the change was not in the Table, there is nothing to do
    If Application.Intersect(Target, lo.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' If there is only one row in the Table, there is nothing to do
    If lo.ListRows.Count <= 1 Then Exit Sub

    ' Count the number of entries in the second last row
    '  if its less than the number of columns, that row is incomplete
    If Application.CountA(lo.ListRows(lo.ListRows.Count - 1).Range) _
      <> lo.ListColumns.Count Then
        ' Delete the last (newly created) row
        lo.ListRows(lo.ListRows.Count).Delete
        lo.ListRows(lo.ListRows.Count).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
        MsgBox "Please enter complete data before starting a new row!", _
          vbOKOnly + vbError, "Undoing last data entry"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting out of range error message at Set lo = Me.ListObjects(1)

Comment: Are you actually using a **Table** ( as you say in your OP)?

Comment: Sorry it was regular text looking like a table so I've changed this.  However, when I try to run the sub it cant find the macro?

Comment: It's a `Worksheet` event handler.  Put it in the relavent worksheet module.  It runs itself in responce to a user data entry on the worksheet.

Comment: If you are not familiar with `Events` a here's a [good place to start](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Events.aspx)

Comment: cheers I'll take a look.  Is it possible to highlight the range as the err message keeps showing because its look at everything.  A:V

Comment: Re your last comment:  my sample code assumes that by _unless all data has been entered_ you mean that every cell (I guess that means columns `A` to `V`) in the last row of the table has a value entered?  If you have a different definition of _all data_ then modify the `If` condition to reflect your requirements. I've added a line of code to select the missing cells.

Comment: As you enter data into a new row, I want the code to look at the previous row (A:V) and make sure data has been entered.  I thought this is what you were trying to achieve but it doesnt work based on the original code